# Auth0 Post User Registration Webtask save to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, auth0

I want to use Auth0 for my project, since I want to use their service to save user & Password, I want to be able to export at least user data to my mongodb database.

Auth0 have some Post User Registration hooks which will be fired once the user successfully signs up so I want to execute my script to save that user to my mongodb database hosted at mlab.

Now, I never used Webtask before, and I don't get it... could someone help me reaching my goal ?

Cheers

EDIT: This is what I am using now:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://username:password@ds115131.mlab.com:15131/dbname");

var UserrSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  email: String,
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("Userr", UserrSchema);

module.exports = function (user, context, cb) {
  var username = user.username;
  var email = user.email;

  var newUserr = {
    username,
    email,
  };
  Userr.create(newUserr, function (err, newlyCreated) {
    if(err) return (err);
    nnewlyCreated.save();
  });
};
```

While using this script I get this error:

```
{
  "message": "Unauthorized extensibility point",
  "statusCode": 500,
  "stack": "Error: Unauthorized extensibility point\n    at Object.is_authorized (/data/sandbox/node_modules/auth0-ext-compilers/lib/authorization.js:15:23)\n    at userRegistrationHandler (/data/sandbox/node_modules/auth0-ext-compilers/lib/compilers/user-registration.js:9:18)\n    at /data/sandbox/node_modules/auth0-ext-compilers/lib/adapter.js:90:20\n    at finish (/data/sandbox/node_modules/auth0-ext-compilers/node_modules/wreck/lib/index.js:351:20)\n    at wrapped (/data/sandbox/node_modules/auth0-ext-compilers/node_modules/wreck/node_modules/hoek/lib/index.js:871:20)\n    at onReaderFinish (/data/sandbox/node_modules/auth0-ext-compilers/node_modules/wreck/lib/index.js:415:16)\n    at g (events.js:260:16)\n    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)\n    at emit (events.js:166:7)\n    at finishMaybe (_stream_writable.js:481:14)\n    at endWritable (_stream_writable.js:491:3)\n    at Writable.end (_stream_writable.js:456:5)\n    at IncomingMessage.onend (_stream_readable.js:498:10)\n    at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:260:16)\n    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:166:7)"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is finding this recently - here is a working snippet. Add this to an Action in Auth0 as described here: https://auth0.com/docs/customize/actions/write-your-first-action

```
/**
 * @param {Event} event - Details about newly created user.
 */

const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");

exports.onExecutePostUserRegistration = async (event) => {
  const newUser = { sub: event.user.sub };
  const client = await MongoClient.connect(event.secrets.MONGO_DB);
  const db = client.db();
  await db.collection("users").insertOne(newUser);
  client.close();
};
```

The user registration process will create an entry in your MongoDB database.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I was running the default code.
You can try clear cookie, login, refresh editor page. 
It helped me.